# Как на golang перезаписать запущенный файл?

Tags: windows, golang

Нужно сделать систему обновлений.
Качаются новые файлы, а потом нужно сам запущенный файл обновить.
Удалить сам себя он не может, т.к. вгружен в память - решил сделать bat файл или другое приложение, которое запустится,удалит его и назовёт его именем новую версию и запустит потом, но получается, что bat файл выполняется не отдельно, а вгружается в саму программу- ну и в результате ничего не происходит.
Как решаются проблемы обновления запущенного файла?

Comment: bat/cmd - файл не может "вгружаться в саму программу"

Comment: @"strangeqargo" он выполняется в данном случае самой программой, а мне надо, что б программа запустила bat файл и закрылась, а он(спустя секунду,когда программа будет точно закрыта) обновит файл и запустит её. Я такое хочу сделать

Comment: так вы его в бэкграунде запускайте. отдельным процессом http://stackoverflow.com/a/1449192/5006740 golang тут прямого отношения к делу не имеет. вам надо почитать побольше про процессы  и операционные системы.

Comment: https://golanglibs.com/category/process-management библиотеки для реализации подобного от ручного презапуска/по сигналу до поллинга веб ресурса на предмет новой версии

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что данная проблема решается так же, как и в других языках.

В большинстве случаев, вместе с основной программой лежит вторая, которую чаще всего называют **updater**, она запускается и обновляет основную, если доступна новая версия.

Answer (score 1):

Ваша программа обновления должна после запуска убивать процесс основной программы (или основная программа должна сама завершаться после запуска программы обновления), тогда сможете заменить запускаемый файл основной программы.

Answer (score 0):

Писать в запущенный файл нельзя. Удалить его на windows тоже нельзя (на linux - можно). Зато его можно переименовать.

Т.е. вы кладёте обновлённую версию программы в ту же папку, например в файл prog_new.exe, затем переименовываете prog.exe в prog_old.exe, а prog_new.exe в prog.exe. После этого prog_old.exe можно удалять.

При этом нужно понимать что есть момент, когда prog.exe не существует (а есть только prog_old.exe и prog_new.exe). В зависимости от задач это можно учеть при запуске программы или просто игнорировать - если копий немного, а последствия такой ошибки легко устранимы.